# How to access values from list of dictionaries in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a dataframe that has a column with a list of dictionaries and for each dictionary I want to be able to extract the values and put them in another column as list. Please see the picture below for example which shows only 1 row of the dataframe. so for  each title shown on the picture I want to extract the values and put them in a list for all the rows in a dataframe

[image: example]

Comment: Add an example that can be copied into a text editor inside a python file

Comment: This looks like it is **not** a dictionary, but a string

Comment: Are you sure you have a list of dict and not a string. What is the output of `type(df['activities'][2])`

Comment: Is it json? `pd.json_normalize`

Comment: The type is a tring yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string as a list of dict then extract the `title keys from each records:

```
import ast

df['activities'].apply(lambda x: [d['title'] for d in ast.literal_eval(x)])
```

Comment: It works, but for each value it creates a new row with all the columns duplicated except for the title column whereas I wanted to put all the values in the title column in a list

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want. Does `df['activities'].apply(lambda x: [d['title'] for d in ast.literal_eval(x)])` is what you are looking for?

Comment: That's correct sir